# How to clone a git-flow style git repository?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using a git repo using [the git-flow branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). I have pushed it to a central repository. How can a new developer joining the project clone it?

Cloning the repository only gives the `master` branch. How can the new developer get the `develop` branch, as well as some feature branches of his choice?

Comment: _Cloning the repository only gives the master branch._ - this is false, clone is a complete clone. `git branch -a` will show all the branches.

Comment: Since `git branch` command only showed `master` branch I assumed it only cloned master branch. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As user1615903 [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758476/how-to-clone-a-git-flow-style-git-repository#comment24143437_16758476), a simple

```
git clone <remote repo url>
```

will already give you all branches from the remote repo, including `master` and `develop`.  You can see all the remote branches in your local clone by using `git branch -r` or `git branch -a`.

From the [Git `clone` doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch -r), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository's currently active branch.

If you want local copies of those branches that you can work on, you can create them with

```
git branch <local branch name> <remote branch>
```

or create the branch and check it out with one command like this

```
git checkout -b <local branch name> <remote branch>
```

Comment: Or if there's only one repo, `git checkout <branch name>` will do the job. See [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html): _If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:_ `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`

Comment: But, doesn't it matter where you create the (local that is a copy of remote) branch from?

Comment: @Saran I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Cupcake Well, if you execute `git branch <local branch name> <remote branch>`, it will branch out from a certain commit you're currently on (e.g. master/HEAD if you didn't do anything after the clone command), wouldn't it? That way remote branch and local branch would not be the same. Or?

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch, which is `master` by default.  So change your central repository's currently active branch to `develop`:

```
cd /path/to/central/repo
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/develop
```

Now when developers clone, their initial branch will be `develop` instead of `master`.